# Rails Heroku database missing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, heroku, rails-postgresql

I'm new to Rails and Heroku.
I don't partly understand system of databases (testing, production, development).

I created two Rails apps. First with Rails' default sqlite db and second with Heroku-supported postgres db. I created simple data and pushed apps to Heroku, but Heroku absolutely ignores my db data.

What I didn't understand? Or could you advice me easier way how I can deploy Rails app? I live in the Czech Republic where Rails's not that widespread so almost nobody can advice me.

**EDIT:**

FIRST APP' DB CONFIG

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

SECOND APP' DB CONFIG

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: poet2_development
  pool: 5
  username: poet2
  password: psql

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: poet2_test
  pool: 5
  username: poet2
  password: psql

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: poet2_production
  pool: 5
  username: poet2
  password: psql
```

Comment: I hope you meant database.yml file(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Heroku uses a different database that you do when you test your app locally in your computer. So, all the data that you create in the database of your app while using it locally is not passed down when you push your app to Heroku.

The solution for adding initial data to your Heroku database is to use seeding: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data. Read the documentation and watch this Railcasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data which should explain you everything

Good luck.

Comment: Oh. This was so confusing. Only thing I understood was that I can give Heroku seeds.db file which creates initial data for me.
I wanted to easily move my local db to Heroku...

Comment: In that case, check this link: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

Comment: I encountered a problem: "time zone displacement out of range" during heroku db:push which (as I found out) causes Ruby 1.9.3, older 1.9.2 allegedly works with this command.
I'm on Windows (can't wait for my new Mac soon) and I expect technologies to work so I can focus on development, not on errors :-(
Thanks so much for your patience tho.